Hardy Weinberg Equilibrium; Homozygous individuals
I have the following exercise that I can't solve:
In a sample there are 16 homozygous A1 allele carriers
(A1/A1) and 24 heterozygous A1/A2 allele carriers. How many homozygous A2 allele carriers (A2/A2) would you need to get an HWE=1 in the sample?
I think there is some information missing, probably an assumption should be made so that the equation can be solved...

Welcome to SE Biology! While you're here, it may be a good idea to take the tour and learn more about how to participate. One feature of the community is that we do ask people to do some minimal research or attempts to answer their questions. For example, I was able to find a variety of resources on understanding HWE with an internet search, e.g. https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/hardy-weinberg-equation-299/. What have you already tried?

This question is similar to: Solving Hardy Weinberg problems. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As per H-W:
a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = 1
where: a + b = 1


We are given:

16 homozygous (A1/A1). So: a^2 = 16/x
24 heterozygous. So: 2ab = 24/x

where x is the total population size (which we don't know)

Rearranging the two equations above:
x = 16/a2
x = 24/2ab
b = 12a/16

Substituting this into a + b = 1:
12a/16 + a = 1
a = 16/28 ~ 0.57
b = 12/28 ~ 0.43

x = 16/a2 = 16/0.57^2 = 49

Therefore:
b^2 = homozygous (A2/A2) / x
homozygous (A2/A2) = b^2 * x = 12/28 * 12/28 * 49 = 9
(which is also 49 - 16 - 24 = 9)

So the population has 49 individuals, comprising 16 homozygous (A1), 24 heterozygous and 9 homozygous (A2).

Thanks for answering. This appears to be a correct answer. I appreciate that you're trying to help this person out, but in the future, I'd recommend the method of helping them to work it out themselves, rather than doing it for them! They haven't really met the bar for an answer according to the homework policy. Side note: LaTeX formatting your equations might make them easier to read.
